# git clone from container using ssh

Tags: ssh, git, docker

I'm trying to clone a repository using ssh from a container at runtime, not during the build. I keep getting prompted for the key phrase for my sshkey (there is no passphrase for the key). Is there anyway to tie the ssh agent from the container to that of the host, or some way to avoid using the container's ssh agent?

edit - I can't comment yet, but as a new user, I'm interested in improving my questions, so if you're going to downvote, at least have the courtesy to leave a comment to tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an ssh agent locally (and you should be), you can expose your ssh agent socket inside your container.  E.g., if we assume there exists an image called `cloner` that contains both `git` and `ssh`, we can run:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/tmp/ssh.sock \
  -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh.sock cloner \
  git clone git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World
```

In the above, we expose the agent socket inside the container using a bind mount, making it available as `/tmp/ssh.sock`. We then set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable inside the container to point at `/tmp/ssh.sock`.

If you're not running an agent, things are a little trickier because ssh is strict w/r/t permissions, and in many cases the user id running inside the container will not match the user id that owns the key file.